# Could you represent this sort of network graph, using latex?

Tags: graphs

This came up on a rpg.stackexchange [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/2583/2788), as an option to represent relations between character with a graph from this [PDF](http://www.adastragames.com/downloads/RPGs/Minimus.pdf) where:

> Every node of this graph is another person who "[who] can do something useful that your character can’t; they’ll ask for something in return." By indicating the from of the relationship and the utility of the relationship in the graph, a very simple social network can be depicted. As players play, changes in the relationship map (page 4) represent real character development.

The suggestion from the answer is:

> To adopt this for a longer game, keep the same map principle and continue drawing in pen. By indicating additional likes and dislikes (also accompanied by a want/need descriptor and potentially in a subgraph if things are too fiddly) you can see easily the predominant attitude of an NPC towards anyone else (is it mostly blue? Is it mostly red? Is it thick? Is it thin?)

I was thinking such a graph could be made via LaTeX, and the .tex file would simply be edited for each change to the graph. As relationships grow the lines thicken or thin, and more people are added.

**Would this be possible, and would this be easy to use, after rigging up with a template?**

Comment: Would it be possible? Yes. Would it be easy? Probably not. Next question…

Comment: Would it be not easy to make the template or not easy to 'run' for different characters?

Comment: It is probably possible with Tikz' object oriented programming capabilities.

Comment: @Frédéric but I'm guessing it's too much hassle to make up a template?

Comment: Whether it is too much hassle for you to make one you have to decide for yourself in terms of benefits vs. time spent. For someone else to make it for you, yes, it's too much hassle imho.

Comment: It's better to ask questions with a smaller scope. If you have a go at doing this, then when you come up against a barrier you're likely to get more helpful advice.

Comment: So the  *answer* is: yes, but it would complicated. I'd accept that as an answer.